# Android-Prestashop user authentication

Tags: android, web-services, prestashop

I'm developing Android App for a website which is Prestashop base.
When I'm signing in the user with email, I receive following value for Password field.

```
"passwd": "$2y$10$UwXekiYUoeH7K8rpi9YxKerHxHQZacMSIG3VKseVQ2fjlGlFRfN4W",
```

All I want to do is, just compare this value with a String(value from password EditText).

After successful comparison, I'll be able to Login the user.
Please help me! how can encrypt String value, to compare with above value?
(or is there any technique to decrypt above password value?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String1.equals(String2)` in a if else statement to get this done.

```
String1 = received password value;
String2 = edittext.getText().toString;  //value from edit text.
if(String1.equals(String2))
{
  //Login sucessfull
}
else
{
  //Failed
}
```

**Decoding:**

```
String password = "$2y$10$UwXekiYUoeH7K8rpi9YxKerHxHQZacMSIG3VKseVQ2fjlGlFRfN4W"; 
byte[] tmp2 = Base64.decode(password); 
String val2 = new String(tmp2, "UTF-8"); // here you will get the decoded value.
```

Comment: I posted the server response. How can i convert String value and compare with "passwd" field?

Comment: i think the response is encrypted you need to decrypt the value and then compare them.

Comment: Any idea? how can i decrypt this value?

Comment: I tried, but it says
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Comment: Which means this `$2y$10$UwXekiYUoeH7K8rpi9YxKerHxHQZacMSIG3VKseVQ2fjlGlFRfN4W` is not a valid base64 string. You need to find out what kind of encryption is done to the passwords.

Comment: I checked! they are using Password_hash() for making hash value of password

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158302/discussion-between-rakesh-polo-and-shahzad-akhtar).